# IOS-How to avoid UIWebview Media player popup in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, media-player

Is it possible to avoid the UIWebview Media Player pop up when a mp3 url detected?

Comment: If a mp3 url detected by uiwebview then it will pop up the media player and play the audio.I dont want the player to play mp3 song.I just need only the mp3 url.How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to block the .mp3 from loading

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request URL]] hasSuffix:@".mp3"]{
    return NO;
    }
    return YES;
    }
```